# Generate a random class and read with regex in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I make this little kind of game. There are 7 switches that trigger other buttons on click to toggleClass 'on' which is defined in jQuery.

The Goal is to get all buttons to the state 'on'.

The problem is, you can easily right-click, choose `Inspect Element`, add the class 'on' and win the game.

So I need to make the classes for these switches random. E.g. 'on-214124712', 'on-307153821369' or 'on-6471649031264'. But they have to share the same prefix which is 'on-'.

How can I generate them differently with every click? And how can I still toggleClass and check hasClass them using regex?

HTML:

```
<h2>You clicked <span id="output">0</span> times</h2>
<div class="switches">
     <div id="switch1" class="switch"></div>
     <div id="switch2" class="switch on"></div>
     <div id="switch3" class="switch on"></div>
     <div id="switch4" class="switch"></div>
     <div id="switch5" class="switch on"></div>
     <div id="switch6" class="switch on"></div>
     <div id="switch7" class="switch"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var count = 0;

$('.switch').click(function () {
    $('#output').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 1
    });
});

$("#switch1").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch3').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch5').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch6').toggleClass("on"); 
    count++;

});
$("#switch2").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch1').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch3').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch7').toggleClass("on");
    count++;

});
$("#switch3").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch2').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch5').toggleClass("on");
    count++;

});
$("#switch4").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    //$('#switch1').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch2').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch5').toggleClass("on");
    count++;

});
$("#switch5").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch1').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch4').toggleClass("on");
    count++;

});
$("#switch6").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch3').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch5').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch7').toggleClass("on");
    count++;

});
$("#switch7").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch3').toggleClass("on");
    $('#switch4').toggleClass("on");
    count++;

});

$('.switches').click(function () {
    if ($("#switch1").hasClass("on") && $("#switch2").hasClass("on") &&   $("#switch3").hasClass("on") && $("#switch4").hasClass("on") && $("#switch5").hasClass("on") && $("#switch6").hasClass("on") && $("#switch7").hasClass("on")) {
        alert('Success!');
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: methinks it [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you not need check state by class, use simple js object instead

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

You can use this selector that checks if the element has a class that contains the desired string (check the updated demo):

```
$('.switch[class*=on-]').addClass('red');
```

---

Each div that has a class that contains `on` will get red

```js
$('.switch[class*=on-]').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switches">
  <div id="switch1" class="switch">test</div>
  <div id="switch2" class="switch on-9876597856978">test</div>
  <div id="switch3" class="switch on-jhg675">test</div>
  <div id="switch4" class="switch">test</div>
  <div id="switch5" class="switch on-876uyg">test</div>
  <div id="switch6" class="switch on-kjhg76gt9">test</div>
  <div id="switch7" class="switch">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thought that's just basic selector, I've found that, but how to but those regex on toggleClass and hasClass